# latest kernel update (.38) doesn't boot in 3D

Tags: 12.04, kernel, updates

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 with Nvdia GE-F card (happily working and installed using [these](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) instructions). Since the last kernel update (3.2.0-38-generic) i can only boot in 2D mode (otherwise it just freezes moments after i log in).

Is there a way to un-roll an update? I need my machine....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From grub you should be able to choose to boot to previous versions. You will then have a list of choices with all the previous kernels.

I just followed [these](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/11/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/) instructions to remove a kernel I didn't want.